# what PEX fittings can I use with a Zurn PEX QickClamp Crimp Rings?

Tags: plumbing, pex, plumbing-fixture

I have [Zurn crimp rings](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003112C74) and the [Zurn ratchet tool](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004Y6F0U6).  I was wondering what brass fitting I can use.  Do they need to be Zurn fittings or can they be any crimp fittings?

[image] [image]

For example, can I use [sharkbite crimp fittings](http://www.homedepot.com/p/SharkBite-1-2-in-PEX-Brass-Lead-Free-Tee-UC362LFA/202270638#.UlVkruaJAuE)? or do I need to use the Zurn crimp fittings?  They look very similar or I can't tell the difference.   Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: The Zurn PEX®
Residential Plumbing Installation Guide http://www.zurn.com/media-library/web_documents/pdfs/brochures/zmktg370-04-pdf does not address this issue. You'd think they would specifically address compatibility one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

PEX labeled fittings are uniform (essentially). You can use any pex labeled fitting with any pex labeled tubing and any pex labeled crimp ring, provided they are all labeled for the same size tubing and the manufacturers literature shows as astm compliant. For ordinary residential remodeling you don't need to be concerned with pressure ratings of the assembly.

Note that PEX labeled components are for use with potable water only, unless otherwise noted in the manufacturers literature (I don't know of any exceptions but they may be out there).

Answer (score -1):

I believe everything labeled as a "PEX" fitting would be compatible without regard to the brand (other than the tool required to fasten the rings)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This sounds like good information, but where did it come from? Some supporting information would be really helpful.

Comment: It's a guess but it's probably correct